# How to find all two pairs of sets and elements in a collection using MapReduce in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, collections, mapreduce, set, reduce

I have a collection of sets, each set contains many items. I want to retrieve all pairs of sets and elements using Spark where each pair after reduce processing will contains two items and two sets 
for example:

If I have this list of sets

```
Set A={1,2,3,4 }
Set B={1,2,4,5}
Set C= {2,3,5,6}
```

The map process will be:

```
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(B,1)
(B,2)
(B,4)
(B,5)
(C,2)
(C,3)
(C,5)
(C,6)
```

**The target result after reduce is:**

```
(A B, 1 2) // since 1 2 exist in both A and B
(A B, 1 4)
(A B, 2 4)
(A C,2 3)
(B C,2 5) 
here (A B,1 3) not in the result because 1 3 not exists in B
```

Could you help me to solve this problem in Spark in one map and one reduce functions in any language ( Python, Scala, or Java)?

Comment: This might be a good code golf question https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you share code to create your rdd instead of python objects?

Comment: Actually, I am new to spark. I am looking for any algorithm that can help me to solve this problem. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break this problem into multiple parts, I consider the transformation from input lists to map output trivial. So let us start from there,

That you have a list of (String, int) looking like

```
("A", 1)
("A", 2)
....
```

Lets forget you need 2 integer elements in result set first, and lets solve for getting intersection set between any 2 keys from the mapped output.

Result from your input would look like

```
(AB, Set(1,2,4))
(BC, Set(2,5))
(AC, Set(2,3))
```

To do this, first, extract all keys from your mapped output (mappedOutput) that is an RDD of (String, Int), convert to set, and get all combinations of 2 elements (I am using a stupid method here, a good way to do this that scales would be to use a combination generator)

```
val combinations = mappedOutput.map(x => x._1).collect.toSet
.subsets.filter(x => x.size == 2).toList
.map(x => x.mkString(""))
```

output would be List(ab,ac,bc), these combination codes will serve as keys to be joined.

convert mapped output to list of set key (a,b,c) => set of elements

```
val step1 = mappedOutput.groupByKey().map(x => (x._1, x._2.toSet))
```

Attach combination codes as key to step1

```
val step2 = step1.map(x => combinations.filter(y => y.contains(x._1)).map(y => (y, x))).flatMap(x => x)
```

output would be (ab, (a, set of elements in a)), (ac, (a, set of elements in a)) etc. Because of the filter, we will not attach combination code bc to set a.

Now obtain the result I want using a reduce

```
val result = step2.reduceByKey((a, b) => ("", a.intersect(b))).map(x => (x._1, x._2._2))
```

So we have the output I mentioned we want at the start now. What is left is to transform this result to what you need, which is very simple to do.

```
val transformed = result.map(x => x._2.subsets.filter(x => x.size == 2).map(y => (x._1, y.mkString(" ")))).flatMap(x => x)
```

end :)

Comment: Thank you Hao Yuan. Your solution is very good. I hope I can dot it in one map and one reduce function

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMohammed I am afraid to do this with exactly one map and one reduce function, you need to make some assumptions about the input. You need to assume you already know the combinations (set ids) prior and you need to assume the input passed to you is already in the format of step1.